# суммирование значений элементов формы

Tags: jquery, javascript

есть динамически созданные 2 элемента...

```
<div id="1">
     <select name="a[]">
          <option value="1">1a</option>
          <option value="2">2b</option>
          <option value="3">3c</option>
          <option value="4">4d</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" value="12">
</div>
<div id="2">
     <select name="a[]">
          <option value="1">1a</option>
          <option value="2">2b</option>
          <option value="3">3c</option>
          <option value="4">4d</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" value="55">
</div>
<div id="3">
     <select name="a[]">
          <option value="1">1a</option>
          <option value="2">2b</option>
          <option value="3">3c</option>
          <option value="4">4d</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" value="182">
</div>
```

Задача... при изменении select - на другое значение суммировать все элементы... Количество блоков динамическое...
В результате по умолчанию должно получится... 12*1+55*1+182*1... При изменении значения id="3" select на 3 - пересчитывать должно 12*1+55*1+182*3...

P.S. Буду признателен за помощь..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

допустим ваши дивы обёрнуты дивом с `id="form"`, тогда:

```
$("select").change(compute);

function compute(){
    var result=0;
    $("#form").children().each(function(){
        var firstValue=$("select option:selected", this).val();
        var secondValue = $("input", this).val();
        result+=firstValue*secondValue;
    });
    alert(result);
}
```

[пруф.](http://jsfiddle.net/RTPq6/)

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1">
     <select name="a[]">
          <option value="1">1a</option>
          <option value="2">2b</option>
          <option value="3">3c</option>
          <option value="4">4d</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" value="12">
</div>
<div id="2">
     <select name="a[]">
          <option value="1">1a</option>
          <option value="2">2b</option>
          <option value="3">3c</option>
          <option value="4">4d</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" value="55">
</div>
<div id="3">
     <select name="a[]" onChange="fct()">
          <option value="1">1a</option>
          <option value="2">2b</option>
          <option value="3">3c</option>
          <option value="4">4d</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" value="182">
</div>
<script>
var txt=new Array();
var stxt=new Array();
var divm=new Array();
for(var n=1;n<3;n++){
divm[n]=document.getElementById(""+n);
divm[n].firstChild.onchange=function(){fct()};
}
function fct(){
for(var n=1;n<3;n++){
divm[n]=document.getElementById(""+n);
txt[n]=divm[n].lastChild.value;
stxt[n]=divm[n].firstChild.value;
alert(txt[n]+" "+stxt[n]);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Смотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/PjS3F/2/)

```
function recalculate(){
    $('#res').text('');
    var sum = 0;
    $('div').each(function(){
        var selectVal = $('select',this).val();
        var inputVal = $('input',this).val();
        $('#res').append(inputVal + selectVal);
        if($(this).index() < $('div').length - 1){
            $('#res').append(' + ');
        }
        sum += (inputVal + selectVal) * 1;
    });
    $('#res').append('<p>Сумма: ' + sum + ' </p>');
    return;
}

$('select').change(function(){
    recalculate();
});
```

Comment: - использовать append в цикле - моветон
- `$('div').length` можно было бы и закэшировать
- `.each()` может принимать функцию, которая принимает индекс текущего элемента, т.о. можно было бы избавиться от `$(this).index()`
- в `.change()` тоже не обязательно предавать анонимную функцию, в которой вызывается именованная, можно просто передать её имя